# Is there a way to increase the sensitivity of a specific point, in the purpose of showing a tooltip?

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highcharts area graph with multiple points. Part of these point are special and therefor are shown by a symbol (image).
When there are other points which are very near a special point, it is very difficult to display the tooltip of the special point. Instead it displays the tooltip of the other point, even when the mouse pointer is right on the special point.
Is it possible some how to make the special point more sensitive to the mouse pointer, so that the it's tooltip will overcome when I move my mouse over it's symbol (image).

Here is an example of what I mean (jsfiddle) - jsfiddle.net/orenise/cgz7t3yq/30 When I go over the sun marker, I wish to be focus on it, and the way it now works is that if I have other points near it, they might get the focus

Comment: If you can reproduce your code in a live example (jsfiddle, codepen) it would be easier for someone to help.

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: Here is an example of what I mean (jsfiddle) - https://jsfiddle.net/orenise/cgz7t3yq/30/
When I go over the sun marker, I wish to be focus on it, and the way it now works is that if I have other points near it, they might get the focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the hover state for those points and switch off the tooltip for them using the tooltip.formatter callback.

Disable hover:

```
  {
    x: 1584339600,
    y: 24,
    id: 'noTooltip',
    marker: {
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    },
  },
```

Tooltip customization:

```
  tooltip: {
    formatter() {
      var output = `<span style="font-size: 10px">${Highcharts.time.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S', this.key)
     }</span><br>
     <span style="color:${this.point.color}">●</span> ${this.point.series.name}: <b>${this.point.y}</b><br/>`
      if (this.point.id === 'noTooltip') {
        return false
      } else {
        return output
      }
    }
  },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zbcvLjx3/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.marker.states.hover.enabled

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it